# How to identify the string in a list through dynamic function added inside a grepl boolean search?

Tags: r, grepl

Would basically like to identify the folder that has the current month. Normally this would work

```
grepl("\\December",dir(Main_Directory)
```

However I would like to do this instead

```
grepl("\\{format(Sys.Date(),format="%B")}",dir(Main_Directory)
```

but it gives an error `Error: unexpected input in "grepl...."`

Comment: Try `grepl(format(Sys.Date(), format="\\\\%B"), dir(Main_Directory))`

Comment: FYI, `\\D` is matching a non-digit character and not necessarily the literal `D`, you may need `\\\\December`.

Comment: C.f., contrast `grepl("\\Dec", c("\\December", "\\Aecember"))` with `grepl("\\\\Dec", c("\\December", "\\Aecember"))`.

Comment: @r2evans you are right, and I have changed the comment to reflect that, though the issue might be more with accidentally matching something like `C:\\months\\not_December`. Probably doesn't make a difference in most use cases, but has the potential to be a very annoying bug. Thanks.

Comment: Great point, and this brings up a fun point: contrast https://xkcd.com/208/ with https://xkcd.com/1171/.